# dojo query does not work on IE7 but does on IE8 and other browsers?

Tags: javascript, dojo

`dojo.query("#foo #bar")` which works as expected in FF, Safari, Chrome and IE8, returns an empty list in IE7.

I'm actually searching for a div with `id = bar` inside another div with `id = foo`.
Did I miss something in my query or is this a known issue in IE7??

Thanks
Jeff

Comment: Are your "id" values completely unique on the page? (They should be.) If they're not, that can trigger weirdness.

Comment: There are legitimate uses of this.  This can be used to detect whether #bar is contained inside #foo in the HTML.  In any case, dojo.query should not come up with different answers if the id's are unique.

Comment: That's a good point, but if the ID's are /not/ unique (in the HTML sent to the browser), getElementById (and I would assume dojo.byId) will only consider the first node with the given ID.

Additionally, if you wanted to check for the existence of id bar within id foo you'd be better to use `dojo.query('#bar', dojo.byId('foo'));` assuming a fairly large DOM

Answer (score 1):

Because ID's are unique you shouldn't ever had to query for two at once. So either modify your query and have a single ID, or, if you need multiple elements with the same 'id', use a class.

For the second option, you would then change your query to `dojo.query('.bar', dojo.byId('foo'))`, which returns elements with class 'bar' that are a child of the element with id 'foo'.